# How to print all characters in this code in C on a linux terminal?

Tags: c, linux, terminal, fgets

I want to read a file and print a line from that file. Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* get_next_line(FILE* fpntr);

int main()
{
    FILE* fp = fopen("movies.txt", "r");
    char* tmp = get_next_line(fp);
    printf("%s", tmp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

char* get_next_line(FILE* fpntr)
{
    char buff[2048];
    int index = 0;
    int ch = fgetc(fpntr);
    while(ch != '\n' && ch != EOF)
    {
        buff[index++] = ch;
        ch = fgetc(fpntr);
    }
    buff[index] = '\0';
    char* tmp;
    tmp = (char*)malloc((int)(index)*sizeof(char));
    strcpy(tmp,buff);
    return tmp;
}
```

Here is the output as displayed from Ubuntu terminal.
[image: Output Image]

The first line in my `movies.txt` file is `1.Lord of the rings the fellowship of the ring`, but only the last few characters are being printed out.So I need help to print out the entire line instead of just the last few characters.

Comment: Is there something that doesn't allow you to use [fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets)? Don't reinvent the wheel if you don't have to.

Comment: Actually I have a lab assignment and I am not supposed to use fgets. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program prints a line without a line terminator.  Apparently, your shell prompt contains code to return the cursor to the left margin before printing the prompt text; and so, the prompt replaces part of the program's output.

With a simpler prompt, you would get something like

```
bash$ ./new
1. Lord of the rings the fellowship of the ringbash$
```

where `bash$` is your prompt.

If this is not what you want, `printf("%s\n", ...)` would be the normal and expected way to print a line with a newline added; or, you could avoid trimming the newline in the first place.  If the program isn't one you can change yourself, adding a newline after running it could be done with

```
bash$ ./new; echo
```

If you change your prompt to always print an empty line before the prompt text, you can avoid this problem altogether, but then you will typically want a rather big terminal window.  (I see you already have one, but I guess that's just because you tolerate Ubuntu's insane default settings.)

Comment: @alk Indeed.  Thanks; fixed.

Comment: Yes I am new to programming and linux in general and hence have the default settings enabled.